# Removing a UITabBarController's view causes an EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, uitabbarcontroller

I'm trying to remove a UITabBarController from a window in my app by calling removeFromSuperview on the controller's view after adding it to the window previously.  However when i do so and after it deallocates all the view controllers that are on the bar successfully, i get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS signal after an autorelease pool is drained.  by method swizzling i've found out that it happens after something called UITableViewRowData has its dealloc method called.  I'm wondering if there's a bug when the more view controller is attempting to be deallocated.  Has anyone else ever run into this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are most likely releasing something you shouldn't be, can't really say what without some sample code

Comment: Possibly, but i don't know what it could be because it seems that all the view controllers owned by the view are released before the crash happens.  This app is relatively complex so it'd be difficult to provide a concise code sample.

Comment: Are u using a tabarviewcontroller? If u are it's very possible that it release ur views for u and u don't need to do so